# Export data from firebase to bigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I have a couple apps using firebase under a project.

I just set up a bigquery which has the project linked.

Under firebase project setting, i see all my apps are currently linking to bigquery. And there is a link i can click on that says "View dataset"

However, it looks like whenever I click on that "View Dataset", the bigquery page doesn't contain any table for my apps?

Is there anything I need to do after the linking, to explicitly instruct firebase to export data to bigquery? Or instruct bigquery to import data form firebase?

Or do i just need to wait?

Comment: You need to wait for data to show up.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard You are correct. Just need to wait. I can accept your answer

Comment: I feel like I didn't help very much, but I added it below as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Zhen, are you talking about the Realtime Database or Firestore? I need to do the same with the Realtime database and it seems it works only for Analytics...

Comment: @Paolo sorry I can't be of any help here, I haven't been maintaining this project so I have no idea what is going on now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase syncs new data to BigQuery periodically, so data won't be available immediately after linking. After the first sync to BigQuery, the datasets will be available.